# QWIK - Propiedad onLoad$ de etiqueta img no funciona con cache del browser

Tags: qwik

Tengo un componente simple con una etiqueta jsx img donde uso la propiedad onLoad$ para renderizar condicionalmente dependiendo de si la imagen está cargada o no. El problema es que cuando la imagen se almacena en caché en el navegador, la propiedad no funciona. En un navegador con pestaña de "incognito" y caché desactivado, funciona perfectamente.
Esto sucede tanto en Firefox como en Chrome.
Este es el componente:

```
import { component$, useSignal, useTask$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";

interface Props {
  id: number | string;
  size?: number;
  backImg?: boolean;
  isVisible?: boolean;
}

export const PokemonImage = component$(
  ({ id, size = 200, backImg = false, isVisible = true }: Props) => {
    const isLoad = useSignal(false);

    useTask$(({ track }) => {
      track(() => id); //como el useeffect, si id cambia se ejecuta lo de abajo
      isLoad.value = false;
    });

    return (
      <div
        class="flex items-center justify-center"
        style={{ height: `${size}px` }}
      >
        {!isLoad.value && <span>Cargando...</span>}
        <img
          src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${backImg ? "back/" : ""
            }${id}.png`}
          alt="Poke Sprite"
          style={{ width: `${size}px` }}
          onLoad$={() => isLoad.value = true}
          class={[
            {
              "hidden": !isLoad.value,
              "brightness-0": !isVisible,
            },
            "transition-all",
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```